# БИТРИКС - как отсортировать свойства элементов раздела, чтобы в выпадающем списке выбора свойств они отображались по алфавиту

Tags: сортировка, битрикс

Например, в админке в настройках раздела выбираем таб "Свойства элементов". В поле добавления нового свойства нажимаем на раскрывающийся список свойств. Можно ли как-то этот раскрывающийся список отобразить в алфавитном порядке?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]